# 'System.InvalidCastException in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'

Tags: vb.net

I have done a little bit of research on different posts and have come to the conclusion that my code as shown below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnGetTime_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetTime.Click
        getTime.ShowDialog()
        lblTime.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, 0, CDate(lblTime.text))
    End Sub
End Class
```

has an error at 'CDate(lblTime.text)'.  Now I've not much of a clue what most of this code means.  I suppose that's how VB works, do now learn later.  The problem is that I can't convert string: lblTime.text to a date format using cDate?  why not?  I'm using cDate()?

The error reads:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Label1" to type 'Date' is not valid.'
```

SOLUTION:

The problem was with a maskedtextbox, I had a string inside of it as a preview.  The issue came from converting that string into a date.

[image]

It should be:

[image]

Comment: `lblTime.Text` contains string `Label1`, which cannot be cast to `DateTime`. Try using a date string that convertible to `DateTime`.

Comment: What is the format of your date?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a string to date. You can use `Convert.ToDateTime` function for that.

```
lblTime.Text = "2018-11-05"

Dim date as Date = Convert.ToDateTime(lblTime.Text)

date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); //to convert back to string.
```

If your date has a custom format, take a look at `DateTime.ParseExact` so you can also specify the format.

You can read about it [here](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html).

If your date is in this format, `11/05/2018`,

```
lblTime.Text = "11/05/2018"

Dim dt as Date = DateTime.ParseExact(lblTime.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)

date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); //to convert back to string
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674024.aspx#CDATE)